# add preceding and trailing text to each string in a text file

Tags: whitespace

i have a text file that has a bunch of links that are are all delimited by whitespace.  i want to add a 'tag' around each link so it looks like this:

```
<g:price>linkfromfilegoeshere</g:price>
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand correctly, but here is an untidy version that would work for smaller files.

```
        string s = File.ReadAllText("FilePath");

        var words = s.Split(new string[]{" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        List<string> tagwords = new List<string>();

        foreach (var word in words)
            tagwords.Add(string.Format("<g:price>{0}</g:price>", word));

        string newtext = string.Join("", tagwords);

        File.WriteAllText("Filepath", newtext);
```

This could be done a lot better, but its a start :) I will update when I have more time later.